# I have URL and ID pairings, and I send the URLs to an API which it returns in no specific order. How should I pair them back up?

Tags: database, api, sorting, dictionary, keyvaluepair

This is a programming problem that I haven't came across yet and I want to make sure I'm tackling it in an efficient manner.

I have an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary consisting of a "url" key and a "id" key with their corresponding values.

I then iterate over this array and throw each URL value into a request object that I then send to an API to be processed.

The API sends them all back at once, not necessarily in the order I sent them with other attributes that I use the API for gathering.

**My question is:** Now that I have all these URLs and their data, how do I match them back with the IDs that they corresponded to in order to add all these attributes (the ID + the new attributes the API returned) into a database?

**My solution:** Create *one* dictionary with the URL of each item as the *key* and the ID as the *value* of the key, and then when I get the URLs back just find the value that responds to that URL key.

Is there a better solution to this problem? Maybe architecturally I should be doing this all differently in a way that better facilitates an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The Best Solution is the way you suggested. If you make a key-value pair the lookup time will decrease considerably as it would be O(1). So mapping them back wont be a problem even if you API call is asynchronous.